# Listview item in the picture control click does not work

Tags: java, android, listview, listviewitem

Thank you for helping me.

In the ViewPager + Fragment contains four pages, including Fragment contains listview Lane in the listview button, listview own click event is also need to use. In the listview item in the button click event, the trigger is not correct. Sometimes click no response, but in the switch Fragment with a button click event response and Fragment switch success

Thanks

Description:

- That is, in the custom adapter to add the imageview click event,
  click response response from time to time response.
- A total of four Fragment fourth page also has the same item in the
  imageview click    event, but no problem arises. This problem occurs
  in the first page.    The two page codes are almost the same.

> ```
> holder.operateInstanceImg.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {          
> @Override
> public void onClick(View v) {
>       String InstanceId = mInstanceModelList.get(position).getInstanceid().toString();
>       String instanceCurStatus = mInstanceModelList.get(position).getStatus();
>       final MenuDialog mdlgClickMenu = new MenuDialog(mActivity,R.style.menu_dialog,InstanceId,instanceCurStatus);
>       mdlgClickMenu.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_mdlgclickmenu);
>       mdlgClickMenu.show();
>   }
> });
> ```

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. Also: We cannot guess what your code looks like.

Comment: can you post a piece of code? and also rephrase your question, because it is not obvious what youre asking about

Comment: I have updated the description of the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

change **new OnClickListener()** to **new View.OnClickListener()**

Comment: current  onclicklistener is android.view.View.OnClickListener